# ##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed

Tags: azure-pipelines

Building CI pipeline. But while building getting the below error.

FrontEnd =>> vue3 + vite

```
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/dist

Finishing: PublishBuildArtifacts
```

### my yml file is :

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "18.x"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"

  - script: 
      npm install
      npm run build
    displayName: "npm install and build"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      artifactName: dist

      pathtoPublish: "dist"
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. What steps have you taken to confirm the output location of the results of your `npm run build` command?

Comment: In vite.config.js, the settings are default and no path is selected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved.

In the script line, only a | sign was enough be put.

correct sample :

```
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "18.x"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"

  - script: |
      npm install
      npm run build
    displayName: "npm install and build"

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      artifactName: dist

      pathtoPublish: "dist"
```